# Google Charts BarCharts missing vaxis

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have a barchart which I am populating with dynamic data. The vaxis sometimes is not visible and in such cases the haxis doesnot start from 0. I apologize I do not have a code snippet for the issue. But if someone might have faced a similar issue could they please let me know of a possible solution.
Would the viewWindow set to min of 0 work for this?

Thanks,
Farhan

Comment: `viewWindow` should work, on a continuous axis (date, number, etc...)

Comment: @WhiteHat thanks!!. I added viewWindow to my vaxis but to no effect. I am not sure whats going wrong, because for some data I am getting the axis for others I am not, also I was not able to replicate the issue in a fiddle.

Comment: it's going to be hard to solve without code, example, image, or something...